# Custom LaTeX commands involving auxiliary files

Tags: macros, auxiliary-files

Can someone with low-level LaTeX knowledge please help me create new customized commands? The commands should be named `\storeitem` and `\typesetitems`, and they should work like this:

```
\typesetitems
\storeitem{hello}

some other stuff

\typesetitems
\storeitem{world}
```

This is what the commands should do:

1. On first run of LaTeX, the `\storeitem` commands should put their arguments into an auxiliary file, in this case "hello" and "world".
2. Each instance of `\typesetitems` (which is assumed to occur the equal number of times as the `\storeitem` command - twice in the above example) **should put all the stored items in a regular bulleted list (itemize) with a normal font, with the exception that the N-th occurrence of `\typesetitems` should typeset the N-th item in an italic font.**

Thus, the results of the above commands would be something like:

[image: items]

A few other things that should be included if possible, for more friendliness and robustness:

1. If the number of occurrences of `\storeitem` and `\typesetitems` don't match, produce a warning. (And do something graceful with the "overflowing" commands, which could be either of them.)
2. If one edits the arguments of existing `\storeitem`s, adds new `\storeitem`s, or deletes existing `\storeitem`s, produce some kind of a "Labels changed, run again" warning message. (Similar to the one that LaTeX does by default when labels have changed.)
3. Maybe later I may not want itemize. Maybe I want numbered lists. Or maybe I do not want lists at all. And maybe I want to do something other to the N-th item than italicize it. For these reasons, it should be rather straightforward to edit the custom commands to suit one's needs.

Comment: why have `\typesetitems\storeitem{world}`  and worry about not having the commands in pairs rather then just having `\storeandtypesetitem{world}` which does both jobs. printing the whole list but italicising the current one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following stores the items in references (`item1`, `item2`, `item3`, …) in the `.aux` file. And the last number is remembered in reference `itemlast`. `\typesetitems`
sets the items in environment `itemize` getting the stored items from references `item1` up to `item<itemlast>`. Two counters are used, `storeitem` counts the stored items and `typesetitems` the number of `\typesetitems`. If at the end of document the two counters differ, a warning is given.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atveryend}
\usepackage{zref-base}
\newcounter{storeitem}
\newcounter{typesetitems}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\storeitem}[1]{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
    \stepcounter{storeitem}%
    \zref@setcurrent{default}{#1}%
    \zref@wrapper@immediate{%
      \zref@labelbyprops{item\the\value{storeitem}}{default}%
    }%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \zref@wrapper@immediate{%
    \zref@setcurrent{default}{\the\value{storeitem}}%
    \zref@labelbyprops{itemlast}{default}%
  }%
  \ifnum\value{storeitem}=\value{typesetitems}%
  \else
    \@latex@warning@no@line{%
      Mismatch store/typeset items:\MessageBreak
      \string\storeitem: \the\value{storeitem}\MessageBreak
      \string\typesetitems: \the\value{typesetitems}%
    }%
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\typesetitems}{%
  \stepcounter{typesetitems}%
  \zref@refused{itemlast}%
  \ifnum\zref@extractdefault{itemlast}{default}{0}>0 %
    \begin{itemize}
      \count@=0 %
    \@whilenum\count@<\zref@extractdefault{itemlast}{default}{0}\relax
    \do{%
      \advance\count@ by\@ne
      \item
      \ifnum\value{typesetitems}=\count@
        \expandafter\textit
      \else
        \expandafter\@firstofone
      \fi
      {\zref@extract{item\the\count@}{default}}%
      \zref@refused{item\the\count@}%
    }%
    \end{itemize}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\typesetitems
\storeitem{hello}

some other stuff

\typesetitems
\storeitem{world}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]